# TypeORM: duplicate key while saving relationships with existing entities

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

I have the following entity in TypeORM:

```js
@Entity('category')
export class Category {

  @Column({ length: 80 })
  public name: string;

  @OneToOne(
    (): ObjectType<Category> => Category,
    (category: Category): Category => category.parent,
    {
      cascade: ['insert', 'update'],
    }
  )
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'parent', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
  public parent: Category;
}
```

Next, I save some categories in my database:

```js
let parentCategory = new Category();
parentCategory.name = 'Parent Category';

let childCategory = new Category();
childCategory.name = 'Child Category';
childCategory.parent = parentCategory;

connection.manager.save(childCategory);
```

Finally, I want to add a new child category of "Parent Category" (consider the parent category was loaded from the database and contains its ID):

```js
let newChildCategory = new Category();
newChildCategory.name = 'New Child Category';
newChildCategory.parent = childCategory.parent; //<- childCategory.parent contains the parent ID

connection.manager.save(newChildCategory); //<- Throws duplicate key error due to cascade
```

One viable solution is defining the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` behaviour, which must be implemented manually according to [this information](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1463#issuecomment-358608773). Is there another solution to do it while saving the entity without having to write the whole query as in my example?

[This GitHub repository](https://github.com/saulotoledo/typeorm-duplicate-key-issue) contains an application replicating the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try

```js
@ManyToOne(
    type => Category,
    category => category.children,
    {
      cascade: ['insert', 'update'],
    }
)
public parent: Category;

@OneToMany(
    type => Category,
    category => category.parent,
    {
      cascade: ['insert', 'update'],
    }
)
public children: Category[];
```

?

I'm not sure it's the root cause of your problem, but `parent`'s type should be `Category` and not `category`. It's strange that you IDE didn't warn you btw.

Watch out, though, because you defined your category-parent relation to be of `OneToOne` type, but from the example you provided you're using it as a `OneToMany`/`ManyToOne` relation!

Comment: The solution did not solve my issue yet. The "category" was a typo I forgot to fix here. I will fix it in my question. I am trying to avoid the "many" part by pointing to the parent only. I created a GitHub repos to replicate the issue. I pasted it in my question to make it easier to investigate.

Comment: By saying `category => category.parent` you're saying that the inverse side of the relation is established on the `parent` prop of the related instance, while it's not true, because if `y` is `x`'s parent, the `x` cannot clearly be `y`'s parent at the same time. Anyway I don't see the logic behind "avoiding the 'many' part". By defining the relation like you did, a category can have one parent category, and can be parent to only one category? Are you sure about that? I completely overlooked that in my main answer btw, my bad. You should define another field for the inverse side.

Comment: I think I got your point. However, even if I use OneToMany I still have the same problem regarding the duplicate keys. I sent a force update to my GitHub repos. If you have time, I created this chat room to discuss: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214610/typeorm

Comment: I updated my original answer to better reflect the changes you should try. I entered the room btw.

Comment: Did you figure out this issue? @saulotoledo ? without using ON DUPLICATE KEY ?